# Constant number of characters in floating point number in bash

Tags: bash

I need to do some "pretty" formatting of numbers with bash. I have a string of comma separated floating point numbers in scientific format (ie. either 3.14159 or 1.0601e-12) and I need to create a comma separated list where all numbers have as many characters. It isn't very important whether spaces or zeros are used for filling (ie. '    3.14' and '3.140000' both work). I tried using printf with "%.12f", but that of course won't work. I'm out of ideas (except for working on a character level, but that seems overly complicated)

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "of course won't work"?

Comment: because printf "%.12f" prints 12 characters after the dot, which means that it for example turns the number 12e-24 into 0... I need to be able to set significant figures rather than decimal places.

Comment: You can't use both field-width and precision modifiers in the same printf statement--at least, not on my system. If you need both, you'll need to code something.

Comment: @CodeGnome: you can't do `printf '%30.16f' 1.0601e-12` on your system?

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Try `printf "%'30.24f\n" 3.140000 3000 1.0601e-12 3000000000`. It may be possible, but the combination of options doesn't always do what you expect--note the width of the 4th line.

Comment: Works fine here across shells, even `printf '%0*.*f\n' 15 7 1234.5678`.

Comment: @CodeGnome: You just need a bigger field width. Try changing it to 38. This is the way every `printf` I've ever used works, whether in C, AWK, Bash, Ksh, Zsh, Python, Perl and many others. You have to guess at what the range is going to be and allocate enough digits or you can use your data to calculate the length you need. Then you can use `printf '%*.*f' 38 24 3.140000 3000 1.0601e-12 3000000000`. Calculating the numbers to use involves some fairly simple string length calculations.

Comment: @CodeGnome POSIX says for zero padding, grouping chars are inserted first, and it's otherwise unspecified. All implementations probably just never count them in the field width rather than make an exception. Anyway I guess grouping can be disabled by the user via LC_NUMERIC=C unless explicitly set in a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to specify a constant number of characters in your output, you can use the *field-width* modifier. For example, to ensure each field has exactly 24 characters:

```
printf "%'24f\n" 3.140000 3000
```

Comment: Thanks, this pretty much solved it, had to use %e instead of %f as Hai Vu's suggested. This solves it `printf "%'12e" 3.140000`

Answer (score 1):

For floating point, use %f, for scientific notation, use %e:

```
$ printf "%12.2f\n" 359.197
      359.20
$ printf "%12.2e\n" 359.197
    3.59e+02
```

Comment: Thank you, just needed to add a ' to your solution to fix my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Zero padding on the left is easier than doing a dynamic decimal precision. Here's a crack at it, not sure if it meets your reqirements.

```
IFS=, read -ra a <<<'1.234567e+3,5432.623,54326e+4,12.26546e+3,1000000000000,2.3641867e+4'

for idx in "${!a[@]}"; do
    printf -v "b[${b:=0}>b&&(b=$b),idx+1]" '%f%n' "${a[idx]}" b
done

for idx in "${!a[@]}"; do
    printf -v 'a[idx]' '%#.*f' $((b - ${#b[idx+1]})) "${b[idx+1]}"
done

# IFS=, declare -a 'b=("${a[*]}")'
# echo "$b"
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
```

which gives

```
1234.567000000
5432.623000000
543260000.0000
12265.46000000
1000000000000.
23641.86700000
```

Though I'd love to see a more elegant way.

Comment: Crap I misread the question - zero or space padding *doesn't* matter. Whelp, shucks.